# Setting arguments in "Java Invocation" section based on a condition

Tags: java, install4j

I am trying to set the arguments but some of the arguments do not need to be present if the option was not ticked during the installation process.

I tried using a compiler variable and setting that programmatically but you can't modify the compiler variable during runtime.

I tried to set a runtime variable and set that programmatically but the actual runtime variable literal is used as intended...

So my question comes down to how I would dynamically generate the arguments under the Java Invocation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For arguments you can define an installer variable with an array content. For example, a "Set a variable" action could have the script

```
new String[] {"one", "two", three"}
```

Then the arguments "one", "two" and "three" would be passed as separate arguments.